# How to Dynamically Stack Multiple Tensors

Tags: python, list, pytorch, tensor, mnist

I'm trying to stack multiple tensors to create a list. In this example, I'd like to stack 10 2x28x28 tensors into a 10x2x28x28 list. However, when I try doing this with tensor.stack(), I get errors.

Context: I'm modifying some MNist data for a neural network, and taking two 1x28x28 MNist images to create a 2x28x28 image. In order to pass this into the neural network, I need to batch these, which necessitates the 10x2x28x28 list.

'''

```
import torch
import torchvision
from torchvision import transforms, datasets
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

train = datasets.MNIST('', train=True, download=True,
                       transform=transforms.Compose([
                           transforms.ToTensor()
                       ]))

test = datasets.MNIST('', train=False, download=True,
                       transform=transforms.Compose([
                           transforms.ToTensor()
                       ]))


trainset = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train, batch_size=10, shuffle=True)
testset = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test, batch_size=10, shuffle=False)


import numpy as np


trainset_mod=[]

#create POSITIVE examples
for k in trainset:
  X=k.copy()
  X_mod=torch.empty(0)#[]
  y_mod=[]

  for i in range(len(X[1])):#len(X[1])):
    X[1][i]=1  #create label for TRUE
    X0_i=torch.cat([X[0][i],X[0][i]],dim=0) #create two-channel image of identical first and second channel
    
    if i==0:
      X_mod=torch.cat([X_mod,X0_i],dim=0)
    else:
      X_mod=torch.stack((X_mod,X0_i),dim=0)
    
    y_mod.append(X[1][i])
    
  trainset_mod.append([X_mod,y_mod])
```

'''

RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [2, 2, 28, 28] at entry 0 and [2, 28, 28] at entry 1

Comment: `torch.stack((X_mod,X0_i.unsqueeze(0)),dim=0)` seems like it would fix the error, though IMO it would make a lot more sense to append `X0_i` to a python list and then call `torch.cat` on the entire list, less memory copying and more elegant.

Comment: For using torch.cat --

  X_2=torch.cat([X_mod[i] for i in range(len(X_mod))])

If i use the above, it produces a 20x28x28 tensor, instead of a 10x2x28x28 tensor

Comment: Try `X_2=torch.cat([X_mod[i].unsqueeze(0) for i in range(len(X_mod))])`